# How to check every file in directory and ask the user to do action in csh shell

Tags: csh, user-input

The actions I would like to do with this script is to

1. Read the name (without base) of each file in a directory
2. For each file, ask the user if he wants to perform an action (e.g. move the file in a directory)
3. Perform or not that action.

   I have problem with while loop and read input. I tried with this:

   #! /bin/csh -f
   set DIR = 'pwd'
   find $DIR -name * -exec basename {} \; | while read filename 
   do
   read -p $filename" (y or n?)" choice
   if ($choice = "y") then
   <>
   endif
   end

but I get the error:

```
find: `basename' terminated by signal 13.
```

I was thinking also to expand the input of the user using again a while until yes or no are given but it's a second order problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Part of your shell code looks like `bash` code even though you use a `#!`-line specifying `csh`. `csh` does not have a `read` command, and this is why you get a `signal 13` error.

Signal 13 is the PIPE signal, and it gets sent to a process when it's trying to write to a dead pipe (a pipe that nobody is reading from the other end of).  The pipe is dead because the `read` call failed in the `while`-loop.  It failed since it's not available in `csh`.

*If* `csh` had had a `read` command, your loop would get filenames, but you would not have had any way of knowing *where* those filenames belonged (in what subdirectory) since you removed the directory path from them. You would therefore not be able to do much with them.

---

The *easiest* way for doing this would be to have `find` ask the question to the user:

```
find . -type f -ok some-action '{}' ';'
```

This would ask for confirmation for each pathname before executing the `some-action` utility with the pathname as its argument. It would ask with the complete command line that would be executed for the given pathname, so it's not quite what you might have in mind.

Note also that specifying `-type f` will find all regular files, while your `-name '*'` test will *always* be true for all types of files, including directories. I'm also using `.` (the current directory)  for the top-level directory for `find`, which is what you seem to want to do with your `DIR` variable.

To manually ask the user for input on each file, and at the same time handle pathnames correctly, the easiest would be to do something like

```
find . -type f -exec sh -c '
    for pathname do
        printf "process %s (%s)?\n" "${pathname##*/}" "$pathname" >&2
        read answer
        case $answer in [Nn]*) continue; esac

        printf "processing %s...\n" "$pathname" >&2
        # process "$pathname" here
    done' sh {} +
```

This assumes a `sh`-like shell, and will spawn `sh -c` for batches of pathnames found by `find`.  The internal shell script would ask the user whether they'd like to process each individual pathname or not.  If the user answers with a word starting with `n` (case insensitive), the next pathname would be considered.

The `"${pathname##*/}"` bit in the code is equivalent to `"$( basename "$pathname" )"` as it removes everything in `$pathname` up to and including the last slash.

The `find` command acts as a sort of *generator of pathnames* for the `for`-loop in the internal script, so piping pathnames or filenames to a `while`-loop is never necessary.

Related:

- [Understanding the -exec option of `find`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389705)